# Feats that use Concentration for a swordsage.

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, optimization, tome-of-battle

I’m playing a Diamond Mind-based swordsage. I’m going to take all of the concentration-based strikes and counters.

If I am loading up my concentration skill, are there any feats I could take that would give additional fun and exciting things to do with my maxed Concentration skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are very few concentration based feats that aren't caster related, and I don't think any are particularly interesting for a swordsage.

- Steady Concentration (RoS 144) - Take 10 on any concentration check
- Offensive Metered Foot (DR 337 p97) - Unarmed strike feat that escalates bonuses to hit.
- Defensive Metered Foot (DR 337 p97) - Unarmed strike feat that escalates AC.
- Discipline (Level 1 Regional Feat, PGF p38) - +2 to concentration and +2 to will
- Born Under the Half Moon (Birth Feat, DR340 p56) - +1 to Balance and Concentration. Expeditious Retreat 1/day.

Comment: (Consider replacing the feat Born under a Half Moon (that doesn't actually *do* anything with the skill Concentration—quite a few feats provide bonuses skill bonuses) with the feat Unnerving Calm (*Tome of Battle* 33)—it's a terrible and annoying feat requiring multiple die rolls for piddly bonuses, but it *does* leverage the skill Concentration.)